# What's the best way to make an inventory spreadsheet that can be updated with Google Forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets

This is my first time playing with Google Script. I'm somewhat familiar with JavaScript but the problem I ran into is way bigger than my knowledge about programming.

I'm trying to make an inventory list for my dealership that can be updated with a Google Form.
The form obviously would import the data entries to a spreadsheet. And I'd like to transfer the entries to another sheet so that I can make it look nicer and share it with everyone at the dealership.

There's only 4 columns : Stock number, Model of the car, Trim, and the status of the stock (Available, Sold, etc).

The problem is, for example if a car comes in (stock number 11), I'd fill the form and add it as available. but later when it gets sold, as I fill in the form again to mark it as sold, it would add a duplicate entry with the same stock number and different status.

I've been trying everything I found on the internet to make it overwrite the old data, but I don't seem to be able to make it happen. I'll add an example file down below. Please let me know where to start.

I also though about writing a google script file to take all the entries on form submit and save it in a variable, and then search for the stock number in the second sheet. if the car was already on the list, it would overwrite the status on the old data. If not, it would simply add a new row for the new entry.

However, like I said earlier, I'm really an amateur when it comes to coding. I can understand a little bit of JavaScript. But I find google script way too overwhelming to work with.

I'll appreciate if anyone could help me out with a solution. Thanks!

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wnZJs619yVmKWpWHC3OXfnANEE5cVvDxEkMJDH5xL2I/edit?usp=sharing
- https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSesWysntKIKaYf4dz7KEJhWyZ1x9OiLxKhHzZ0IyPh4D2rrsg/viewform?usp=sf_link

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Both your links have failed: the spreadsheet is in trash, and the form is not taking responses.

Comment: May I try to clarify, please correct me if I am wrong. You have a form that provides information about your cars. Each car has a unique ID, but there may be several form responses  that relate to a car - bought, sold, transferred, etc. You have a sheet that shows your inventory; the source for this is the form responses. Each car should appear only once in the inventory, however if you copy each new form response then you risk creating multiple entries for some cars. Your question is how to update the inventory sheet so that there are no duplicate entries.

Comment: heya ! well it's totally possible to do what you want. Gscript can edit/add Data to another Spreadsheet by using the Spreadsheet-ID and before adding or editing data can be also checked if certain data is already there ;) The problem is you have to write a lot of stuff by yourself...do you have already tried some scripts to get familiar with Gscript? if not i would suggest look here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus it's a vey basic guide to get some knowledge after that you can easily expand your functions to (add rows, edit rows, etc. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a Google Form form to record stock transactions; there are only four fields, the StockNumber (which is unique to each car), Model, Trim and Status. Form responses are recorded in your spreadsheet. In the same spreadsheet, you have another sheet that acts as a stock status report - the stock report should have only one line for each car. You have a script with updates the stock status from the form responses, but this results in duplicate records.

The solution depends on establishing whether the Stock Number in the Form Response is (or is not) already recorded in the Stock Status. Since the stock status allows only one record per car, if the Stock Number is already on the Status, then the existing record should be updated; if the the Stock Number is NOT on the Stock Status, then it must be a new vehicle, and the form response details should be appended to the Stock Status.

---

The aspects of the script are:

- Install the script as an Installable "onFormSubmit" trigger.
- `var invRange = inventory.getRange(invfirstRow, 1, invLR-invfirstRow+1, 4);` create a range for the entire sheet (exluding headers) and `getValues()`
- `var invID = invValues.map(function(e){return e[0];});`: create a temporary array containing only the Stock Numbers from Column A of the Stock Status.
- `var formID = parseInt(e.values[1],10);`: use Event Objects, to get the form Responses; convert the Stock Number from a string into a number.
- `var formchk = invID.indexOf(formID);` test whether Stock Number from the Form Response can be found in the temporary array of Stock Numbers from the Stock Status. If the test value equals -1, then it is not in the list; otherwise, it is on the list and  the test value is the index of the Stock Number in the list.
- `invValues[formchk][3] = formStatus; invRange.setValues(invValues);`: if the test value is not -1, then update the Values array, and then update the range.
- `inventory.appendRow([formID, formModel, formTrim,formStatus]);`: if the test equals -1, then append a new row to the Stack Status.

---

```
function so5886920702(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var invsheetname = "inventory";
  var inventory = ss.getSheetByName(invsheetname);
  var formsheetname = "Form Responses 1";
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName(formsheetname);

  // get inventory data
  var invLR = inventory.getLastRow();
  var invfirstRow = 4;
  var invRange = inventory.getRange(invfirstRow, 1, invLR-invfirstRow+1, 4);
  //Logger.log(invRange.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var invValues = invRange.getValues();

  // get a list of the Stock Numbers
  var invID = invValues.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  // Logger.log(invID);//DEBUG

  // get latest Form response
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); //DEBUG
  var formID = parseInt(e.values[1],10);
  var formModel = e.values[2];
  var formTrim = e.values[3];
  var formStatus = e.values[4];
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: ID = "+formID+", Model = "+formModel+", Trim = "+formTrim+", status = "+formStatus);

  // check the inventory ID list for the FormID
  var formchk = invID.indexOf(formID);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the form ID = "+formID+", and the formchk value = "+formchk);

  // if formchk is -1, then the Stock Number was not found, otherwise the Stock Number was found
  if (formchk != -1){
    // the car is already in the inventory
    // update the values array
    invValues[formchk][3] = formStatus;

    // update the range
    invRange.setValues(invValues);
  }
  else{
    // the car isn't in the inventory list, so add the car
    inventory.appendRow([formID, formModel, formTrim,formStatus]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Utilize (https://www.utilize.app). The platform helps convert spreadsheets into user-friendly mobile apps. It will help you solve this particular use-case very well.

P.S. I'm the founder of Utilize.